# handle 1gb data file to read words and calculate max length word?

Tags: java, spring, file, large-files, r.java-file

i wrote this code but its going to fail on 1gb size file.

```
public class TestFiles {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int minLength = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int maxLength = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        String minWord = "";
        String maxWord = "";
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            File myObj = new File("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\java.txt");
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                String data = myReader.nextLine();
                String[] dataArray = data.split(" ");
                List<String> list = Arrays.asList(dataArray);
                for (String s : list) {
                    if (s.length() < minLength) {
                        minLength = s.length();
                        minWord = s;
                    } else if (s.length() > maxLength) {
                        maxLength = s.length();
                        maxWord = s;
                    }
                }
            }
            myReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        System.out.println("min length " + minLength + " - max lenth " + maxLength);
        System.out.println("min length word " + minWord + " - max lenth word " + maxLength);
    }
}
```

could you please answers? how can i solve this?

Comment: You don't seem to keep the words so I'd suggest streaming the lines. Have a look at `Files.lines(Path)`. From there you might be able to use `flatMap()` to map the stream of lines to a stream of words and then `max()` with an appropriate comparator.

Comment: "its going to fail": how does it fail? Exception? Please describe!

Comment: probably memory problem

Comment: probalby/obviously: 1gb data but no single(/too few) line breaks!!

Comment: don't do it "line-wise", do it "word-wise!!! ;) (don't `nextLine()` ..only `next()`!)

Comment: ..and you maximum memory consumption will be "the length of the current word" + some constant overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem gets obvious, when 1gb words are squashed into 1 line!*

Solution: Not to process the input "line-wise", but "word-wise", which is suf- & efficient! ;)

Voila:

```
public class TestFiles {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int minLength = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int maxLength = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    String minWord = "";
    String maxWord = "";
    try {
        File myObj = new File("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\java.txt");
        Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
        while (myReader.hasNext()) {
            String word = myReader.next();
            if (word.length() < minLength) {
              minLength = word.length();
              minWord = word;
            } 
            if (word.length() > maxLength) {
              maxLength = word.length();
              maxWord = word;
            }
          }
        }
        myReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    System.out.println("min length " + minLength + " - max lenth " + maxLength);
    System.out.println("min length word " + minWord + " - max lenth word " + maxLength);
  }
}
```

---

*when "many" words are in one line, then we could get problems here:

- `myReader.hasNextLine()`,
- `String data = myReader.nextLine()` and
- `String[] dataArray = data.split(" ");`

---

@huy's answer also correct: the `else` is "efficient for most cases", but is "incorrect for corner cases".

Comment: You are right, I meant FileInputStream https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html

Answer (score 1):

```
int len = s.length();
if (len < minLength) {
    minLength = len;
    minWord = s;
} 
if (len > maxLength) {
    maxLength = len;
    maxWord = s;
}
```

Your test case will fail if large string is located at first index of first line.

Btw, I think you should break your big test to small test, try to find small string and large string for single line, after that multi lines and data from files

Comment: You might want to make your answer a little easier to read, i.e. I almost missed the "remove the _else_" part.

Comment: Does it work, i hate the editor of stackoverflow, it's hard to use. ^^

Comment: Btw, I would add some more explanation why the `else` should be removed, e.g. by some example to help those that might struggle with the concept.

Comment: Your test case will fail if large string is located at first index of first line. Btw, i think you should break your big test to small test, try to find small string and large string for singe line, after that multi lines and data from files.